# bind_class and lambda doesn't work well

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with bind_class function.

```
for line in cat_list:  # insert category into Text widget
    fr = Frame(ft, bg='purple', width=200)
    fr.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

    ent = Entry(fr, width=35, bg='orange', fg='white')
    ent.pack(side='left', expand=1, fill=BOTH)

    ent.insert(0, line[1])

    ent.bindtags(tagList=['Entry', 'add_cat'])
    ent.bind_class('add_cat', "<Return>", lambda event, line=line, ent=ent: sqlite.update_category_name(event, db, line, ent))

    imgsd = pil_image('imgs/required/btns/ch_pic.png', 30, 30)
    img_location = Button(fr, image=imgsd, borderwidth=2, relief="groove", fg='white', anchor='w', command=lambda line3=line:chPic(line3))
    img_location.image = imgsd
    img_location.pack(side='left', expand=0, fill=BOTH)
    img_location.bindtags(tagList=['Button', 'add_cat'])
```

the line `ent.bindtags(tagList=['Entry', 'add_cat'])` works fine. `Entry` is for Entry's behavior and `add_cat` is used for scrollbar binding.

The problem is in next line, because lambda doesn't keep reference to line object, instead it always returns the last 'line' in cat_list.

example: if `cat_list = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `i` will always return 5 in my function "sqlite.update_category_name" instead of 1,2,3,4,5 respectively

Answer (score 0):

As it's name implies, `bind_class` binds to a *class* of widgets, not a single widget. Each time you call `bind_class` within a loop you replace any previous calls to `bind_class`.

If you want each widget to have a unique binding, use `bind` rather than `bind_class`.

```
ent.bind("<Return>", lambda event, line=line, ent=ent: sqlite.update_category_name(event, db, line, ent))
```

Comment: i tried, it didn't work at all, that was my first try, bind instead of bind_class but it didn't work. It was like ...

ent.bindtags(tagList=['Entry', 'add_cat'])
    ent.bind( "<Return>", lambda event, line=line, ent=ent: sqlite.update_category_name(event, db, line, ent))

 but no effects, actually no calls for function at all

Comment: what i dont understand is , why bind_class makes lambda not working good

Comment: @DušanAtanacković: it is because you keep overwriting your binding on each iteration of the loop. A class binding is a _single_ binding on a _class_ of widgets. It has nothing to do with `lambda`. This is simply the case that the last time you call `bind_class` is the only binding that is used by tkinter.

Comment: ok, but what i have to do to make it works since regular bind doesn't call function at all?
If you have time to participate and debug, i make whole code public on git ,here is the link https://github.com/Dusan92Atanackovic/luqi

that is in  _add_gui_category function in file new luqi.py

Comment: @DušanAtanacković: you would use a regular bind. You say it doesn't work, but it should. I see no reason why it won't.

Comment: It works when i comment this line (ent.bindtags(tagList=['Entry', 'add_cat'])), but than the scroll doesn't work because i am binding scrollbar events like this ( 
'
parent.bind_class("add_cat", "<4>", lambda event: scroll_bar_cat.scroll_linux(event))
    parent.bind_class("add_cat", "<5>", lambda event: scroll_bar_cat.scroll_linux(event)))'

Comment: If you don't believe me clone git repository and try it for your self.

Comment: @DušanAtanacković: Sorry, I am not going to clone your repository. I can guarantee that binding to individual widgets is the right (though not only) solution here. If you can't make it work, ask a new question and include a [mcve] that duplicates your problem.